# What's point of the instruction "push 0FFFFFFFFh" after a new stack frame establishing?

Tags: reverse-engineering, disassembly

The instruction `"push 0FFFFFFFFh`" appears that just after a new stack frame within the callee is established,e.g.,

```
push        ebp  
mov         ebp,esp  
push        0FFFFFFFFh  <===HERE          //[ebp-4] is set to 0FFFFFFFFh
push        0255F58h                      // SEH EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION.handler
mov         eax,dword ptr fs:[00000000h]  
push        eax                           // SEH EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION.prev
sub         esp,0D8h  
push        ebx  
push        esi  
push        edi  
lea         edi,[ebp-0E4h]                      
mov         ecx,36h                       // 36h * 0CCCCCCCCh
mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh  
rep stos    dword ptr es:[edi] 

mov         eax,dword ptr [__security_cookie (025A004h)]  
xor         eax,ebp  
push        eax  

lea         eax,[ebp-0Ch]  
mov         dword ptr fs:[00000000h],eax  // Install new EXECEPTION_REGISTRATION
lea         ecx,[intobj]  
call        A<int>::A<int> (0251389h)  
mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],0           //[ebp-4] is set to 0 
call        A<int>::PrintNum (025139Dh)  
mov         dword ptr [ebp-0E0h],0  
mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],0FFFFFFFFh  //[ebp-4] is set to 0FFFFFFFFh again, then [ebp-4] keeps the value in this callee. 
lea         ecx,[intobj]  
call        A<int>::~A<int> (025138Eh)  
mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-0E0h]
...
```

What's point of this instruction "push 0FFFFFFFFh"?

**[C++ Source Code]**
  [image: C++ Source Code]

[UPDATE] Apr 4 2018

Using Windbg, I can make sure the instruction "push 0FFFFFFFFh"(see "Here" in disassembly code) is nothing with SEH, though I still don't know what's point of this instruction "push 0FFFFFFFFh"?

```
0:000> dd fs:[0] l4
0053:00000000  0046fec0 00470000 0046d000 00000000

0:000> dt _Exception_registration_record 0046fec0
test!_EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION_RECORD
   +0x000 Next             : 0x0046ff28   _EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION_RECORD <== eax
   +0x004 Handler          : 0x00255F58   _EXCEPTION_DISPOSITION test!__scrt_stub_for_acrt_uninitialize+0  <== 0255F58h

0:000> dt _Exception_registration_record 0x0046ff28
test!_EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION_RECORD
   +0x000 Next             : 0x0046ff84 _EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION_RECORD
   +0x004 Handler          : 0x00283100     _EXCEPTION_DISPOSITION  test!_except_handler4+0

0:000> dt _Exception_registration_record 0x0046ff84
test!_EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION_RECORD
   +0x000 Next             : 0xffffffff _EXCEPTION_REGISTRATION_RECORD
   +0x004 Handler          : 0x77875845     _EXCEPTION_DISPOSITION  ntdll!_except_handler4+0
```

Comment: and what is after that in the code?

Comment: The point is whatever the programmer is doing with that value later on in the code.

Answer (score 3):

Since SEH is a linked list there are actually two addresses.

The first one is the address of the next handler (in case of chaining) or 0xFFFFFFFF (-1) is this is the last one. The next one is the actual SE Handler.

An old but good read about SEH is ["A Crash Course on the Depths of Win32™ Structured Exception Handling"](http://bytepointer.com/resources/pietrek_crash_course_depths_of_win32_seh.htm).

Comment: ，you don't read the article which you mentioned. Sulely, 0xFFFFFFFF is the last handler in SEH, but in this disassembly code,0xFFFFFFFF is nothing with SEH.

Comment: @MattElson: yes it *is* part of the SEH setup. step through it in the debugger and check the situation after the write to fs:0.